# Split CSV or XLSX by dates and set max filesize

Tags: python, split

In order to split files by setting an approximate filesize (based on max rows) I am using the below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import sys
import os

def split(filehandler, delimiter=',', row_limit=70000,
          output_name_template='LARGE EXCEL/OUTPUT/output_%s.csv', output_path='.', keep_headers=True):
    import csv
    reader = csv.reader(filehandler, delimiter=delimiter)
    current_piece = 1
    current_out_path = os.path.join(
        output_path,
        output_name_template % current_piece
    )
    current_out_writer = csv.writer(open(current_out_path, 'w', newline=''), delimiter=delimiter)
    current_limit = row_limit
    if keep_headers:
        headers = next(reader)
        current_out_writer.writerow(headers)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i + 1 > current_limit:
            current_piece += 1
            current_limit = row_limit * current_piece
            current_out_path = os.path.join(
                output_path,
                output_name_template % current_piece
            )
            current_out_writer = csv.writer(open(current_out_path, 'w', newline=''), delimiter=delimiter)
            if keep_headers:
                current_out_writer.writerow(headers)
        current_out_writer.writerow(row)

split(open('LARGE EXCEL/FILE.csv', 'r'));
```

I want to alter the above to make each files has unique dates (rows from one day should only be shown in 1 file). Unless, there is a completely different solution I can't think of.